# std compliant stringstream using stack allocated storage?

Tags: c++

Can't seem to find anything currently available in the wild, which seems odd.

So before I roll my own, does anyone know of a std compliant stringstream which allocates storage on the stack?

I'm thinking of 2 ways to achieve this:

Initially use a statically sized buffer on the stack (probably a template parameter to allow compile-time customization)

1. When space runs out revert to using dynamic storage
2. When space runs out use `alloca` to increase the stack storage

This will allow quick input into a stringstream for strings shorter than the predetermined size.

A suitable choice for the initial size will mean that things like logging can be achieved without frequent resizing from the heap.

Comment: You can't use `_alloca` for that, since it won't affect the stack of your caller (i.e. the function using the stringstream).

Comment: I have a logging object which currently uses an internal stringstream object to store the logged string. Multiple calls to `operator<<`, as the string is built up, can cause several heap allocations. If I can use a stringstream class which uses stack allocated storage to store the current log line, this will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the same benefits by using `std::basic_stringbuf<char, char_traits<char>, pooled_allocator>`, where you only have to write the pooled allocator.

Then just create a `basic_iostream` attached to that buffer.

Or, create a new class derived from `basic_streambuf`.

But don't rewrite `stringstream`.  The iostreams library is designed by extension by replacing the buffer object.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I found this [stack_allocator](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/stack_container.h?view=markup) from the chromium project, but have not had success using it. Think my knowledge of `std::basic_ostream`/`std::basic_stringbuf` etc is not strong enough at the moment.