# How to write an efficient string buffer

Tags: c++, string, performance, buffer

I need a way build a string. I do not know the size, and it must be very efficient.
Today I use this:

```
std::strstreambuf* sBuf = new std::strstreambuf(20*1024*1024);
std::ostream* outS = new std::ostream(sBuf);
(*outS) << ... << ...
... 
CString outputStr = (*outS).str();
```

When profiling this, I can see that operator<< takes a long time. Its overflow function is called, and takes a long time (25% of my process time). I do not understand why

1. Why does overflow is being called? Why does it takes so much time?
2. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What will be in the string?

Comment: The CString (outputStr) is going for another calculation.
So - I need a way to write strings with operator << into a CString as efficient as possible

Comment: Yes, got that, but if they are only strings, why do you not simply concatenate them with `+` and output `c_str()` afterwards?

Comment: first, I want to allocate memory as little as possible, and using + might cause reallocating again and again.
second, behind the ... in the above sample, hides a huge amount of code, that relies on using <<
So - I must use << and not +

Comment: That was, what I initially wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that `overflow` gets called, because there is not enough space in the buffer. Now, when the newly allocated buffer again only provides a small enlargement, `overflow` will get called again soon.

To overcome this situation, it might be worth implementing a `std::basic_stringbuf` with a custom allocator which in turn will allocate more space or do allocation smarter, e.g. allocate more if the previous allocation was quite large and so on. A rough idea is provided in "[std compliant stringstream using stack allocated storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620383/std-compliant-stringstream-using-stack-allocated-storage)".